# How do I take a prompt response and send it to a text file?

Tags: shell, scripting

I want to ask the user what is their `ORACLE_SID`, `ORACLE_HOME`, and then send the output in a file.

I want to create a param file that has

```
ORACLE_HOME=
ORACLE_SID=
```

that is grabbed from what the user type in. I have this and it works for exporting but I'm not sure how to send it to the file:

```
read -p "Enter ORACLESID: " myvar
export ORACLE_SID=$myvar
```

I would like to send `ORACLE_SID` to a file.

Comment: are you just searching for `echo "ORACLE_SID=$var" > file` ?

Comment: Can you please explain this portion "ORACLE_SID=""$var"?

Comment: 1) `var=abc` 2) `export ORACLE_SID=$var` 3) `echo "ORACLE_SID=$var" > file` 4) text written in file: "ORACLE_SID=abc" (no quotes) - make sure to use `>> file` if it is meant to be appended. Is that what you meant?

Comment: This works perfectly I will give you credit as soon as I am able to. @Fiximan what advice do you have for me learning more shell scripting. I notice its hard to practice if I dont have anything to script. Can you pleasee give me advice.

Comment: Start by looking at existing shell scripts, either online or various system scripts under `/etc/` or wherever. You won't understand all of them, but can look up the syntax you don't recognise in `man bash` or online, and ask a question if you can't find the answer yourself. Similarly, commands you don't recognise will probably have their own man pages.

Comment: Oh and @Fiximan - you'll need to post that as an answer to collect the sweet kudos.

Comment: @Useless ah, well those - will do so it can be flagged as answered. As for learning: in my experience I advanced the most by having to solve my problems rather than sticking to a teaching routine. A small introduction might be helpful of course.

Comment: How do I flag this as answered and its not allowing me to say you gave the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `echo` command will repeat any string it is fed as argument while interpreting wildcards and variables:

```
 echo ABC $USER
```

result

```
ABC myusername
```

So now you can just print the variable that was read in with `read -p "Enter variable" var` to the terminal via

```
echo $var
```

or with additional text as

```
echo "ORACLEVAR=$var"
```

result:

```
ORACLEVAR=userinput
```

for redirecting this to a file, use > (overwriting file) or >> (append to file)

```
echo "ORACLEVAR=$var" >> file
```

So best to use > for the first entry to overwrite old settings and then >> for not deleting any given input.

Comment: For OP's reference: the `$variable` part is [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), and the `>` part is [Redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Output)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get some prompt results into a file using `script`.

1. Typed `script` and press enter, then script start recording your shell and writing to a file.
2. Type the command you want the result, example `history` and press enter.
3. Last you stop your `script` recording using `exit`.

After that you will find your **typescript** named file inside your working folder.

For my purpose it was very useful.

Comment: where do this answer the question ?

Comment: I think this answers a different question (saving a transcript) rather than what was asked (save a specific bit of user input), but certainly the asker can chime it to clarify.

Comment: @dhag - Thanks for clarifying the question, that was a proper comment.